# Div does not drop shadow on neigbour div if the background color of a neigbour div is set

Tags: html, css

I got two divs. One next to another.

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

When the background color of the first div is not set, than the second div drops shadow on the first one as you would normally expect it to. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a46zueo9/1/

```
#first {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #000;
float: left;
```

}

```
#second {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid red;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;        
margin-left: 100px;
}
```

But if the first div has some background color set, than the second div stops dropping shadow on it.

```
#first {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #000;
background-color: #4af;
float: left;
```

}

```
#second {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid red;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;        
margin-left: 100px;
```

}

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a46zueo9/

I was wondering if it's normal behavior. If so, than why? If not than how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes its a normal behavior in first example that div is like a frame with nothing in the background to support

but in second example it have base so its like a sheet which can cover

to solve it

```
first{
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

second{ z-index: 2;
    position: relative; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `z-index` problem, because when there is no `background-color`, than it's transparent. Use `#second{ z-index: 6; position: relative;}` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a46zueo9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `marging-left` from second div, and add `float: left;` on it.